# How do I trigger a child's component function from the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I know this can be done using refs but apparently that is not a recommended approach when creating react applications.  What I want to do is when I click on the parent container, I want to execute Element1 and Element2's 'randomFunction'.

```
class Logo extends Component {
    executeChildFunctions = () => {         
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.executeChildFunctions }>
              <Element1 />
              <Element2 />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends Component {
    randomFunction() {
        ...do something
    }
    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Is this even achievable without using refs?  I feel like I'm not even supposed to be able to do this because it violates react's philosophies.

Comment: Your intuition is correct---`randomFunction` should be defined on the parent, if the click handler is being called there. Now that being said, if you have a really good reason to do this.. there are ways of doing it without using `refs`, but you'll have to make a good case for why you don't keep the function on the parent

Comment: So there are div elements in the child that I add animations to.  I'm dealing with svg's and there are elements inside that I animate individually.  If I were to move the function animations to the parent, how would I be able to pinpoint the element in the child from the parent??